# How to display bank account connected in Stripe Payment with ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments, payment

After [the account](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/object) created and linked to [the bank account](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_bank_accounts/object)
I want to view them after linking successfully. Typical as this below design:
[image]

I have try installed @stripe-js and @react-stripe-js package but I don't see any possible components.

Is there any solution for me?

Thanks!

Comment: StripeJS doesn't have bank component for display purpose. The only way is to retrieve account details from API (/v1/accounts/{account_id}) including external bank accounts and display the bank information on your own.

Comment: I also thought about that too, and I don't know which components in the @stripe-js/@react-stripe-js package can implement them

Comment: `@stripe-js` and `@react-stripe-js` are client libraries. Account retrieval (https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/retrieve) should be done at the server, then pass bank information to the client to display.

Comment: Thank for your recommendation getting account info, however, I want to display them with reactjs component without customize html/css

Comment: I don't think displaying bank account is supported in `@stripe-js` and `@react-stripe-js`.